# Quote indentation problem

Tags: spacing, indentation, quotation

I wanted to make a quote and now there are two problems.

1. I don't want the indent at the beginning
2. LaTeX seems to ignore my `~`, but I want this line to have an indentation

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

{
``Five years ago I would certainly have said that we don't do full-text machine translation, it's too complicated for us", recalls Frahling. "Google had developed its old system over ten years with a lot of people and messing with it just didn't make sense." \\
~~~~~~~~ -- Gereon Frahling, founder of DeepL 
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `quote` environment, and `\hspace*{}` to do the spacing.  If for some reason you don't want the changed margins of the `quote` environment, you could add `\noindent` at the beginning of the quote instead, but then you'd also need some manual vertical space to set it apart from the rest of the text. But quotes are typically set with narrower margins to show that they are quotes.

Personally I would not use `\\` here either, but simply a blank line, which will give you a nicer vertical spacing between the quote and the name line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
This is some text with a regular paragraph indent.
\begin{quote}
``Five years ago I would certainly have said that we don't do full-text machine translation, it's too complicated for us", recalls Frahling. "Google had developed its old system over ten years with a lot of people and messing with it just didn't make sense." \\
\hspace*{1cm} -- Gereon Frahling, founder of DeepL 
\end{quote}
This is some more text.  If this should start a new paragraph, precede it with a blank line in the source.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I wanted an unindented quotation in Lyx, and had to choose "quote" instead of "quotation".